# arbitrary operation on list

Tags: python, list

```
["add",["subtract",["multiply",2,["add",1,3]], 4 ] , 5 ]
```

how can I do these operation

when prog see "add" it adds 1 and 3 and return 4  new list became

```
["add",["subtract",["multiply",2, 4 ], 4 ] , 5 ]
```

when prog see "multiply" it does 2*4 nd return 8 new list became

```
["add",["subtract",8, 4 ] , 5 ]
```

after one recursion

```
["add",4 , 5 ]
```

after last recursion

```
return 9
```

Comment: Tell us what you have done so far and what went wrong.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: Is this homework? I can implement specifications for you, but that costs money. I'll also help you with a problem for fun, but you have to try by yourself first and actually run into problems. Otehrwise you won't learn.

Comment: I have tried to write with iteration but I failed so erased , now,again I am at start point.SO I have no code in my hand

Comment: really, say me are there any homework in that format

Comment: @fatai, I had my first CS homework in this format, really.

Comment: @fatai: It looks exactly like homework. And we don't mind homework, but then you should tag it as homework.

Comment: The solution is a word you use in the question: *recursion*.

Comment: @Ismail, your teacher I think a bit lazy, I have found this question in python book ( in exercise part )

Comment: That's close enough to homework. :-)

Comment: If you think it is as homework , you can tag it

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation#Postfix_algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is sketch it out visually as a tree:

[image]

If you look at the left child (subtract, multiply / 4, etc) you see it is also a tree; and so is the left half of that (multiply, 2 / add, etc).

In fact, you can think of each node with its descendants as being a tree, consisting of either (a) an operator, with a left sub-tree and right sub-tree, or (b) a value (leaf node, no more descendants).

```
to evaluate a tree:
  if it is a value:
    you have the final value; return it
  otherwise, it is an operator:
    evaluate the left sub-tree
    evaluate the right sub-tree
    do operation(left-tree-value, right-tree-value)
    return the result
```

You will notice that 'evaluate tree' calls itself to operate on the sub-trees - this is recursion, where solving a problem depends on solving smaller versions of the same problem and then combining the results.

So the final evaluation order looks like:

```
what is tree value?
    add: {tree1} + {tree2}
    what is tree1?
        subtract: {tree3} - {tree4}
        what is tree3?
            multiply: {tree5} * {tree6}
            what is tree5?
            2
            what is tree6?
                add: {tree7} + {tree8}
                what is tree7?
                1
                what is tree8?
                3
                add: 1 + 3
            4
            multiply: 2 * 4
        8
        what is tree4?
        4
        subtract: 8 - 4
    4
    what is tree2?
    5
    add: 4 + 5
9
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write a recursive function that goes through the lists and do the operations.

It's actually fairly trivial, but I don't want to just hand you the answer, especially since it sounds like homework. :) So update your question with what you tried to do, and we'll tell you where you are going wrong.

Comment: can give me any example or page  I will look them then I will try to write with recursion

Comment: @fatai: Recusion is when you write a function that call itself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479343/how-can-i-build-a-recursive-function-in-python

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator

def do_math(op):
    try:
        return getattr(operator, op[0][:3])(*[do_math(arg) for arg in op[1:]])
    except TypeError:
        return op

L = ["add",["subtract",["multiply",2,["add",1,3]], 4 ] , 5 ]
print do_math(L)
```

Comment: I think your program will crash , something like unary operator you forget to consider

Comment: Not the way I'd write it (I am thinking about the try/except), but that's the idea. @gcc: why? unary operators should work fine.