# Coding summation formula and recursive function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python beginner, running 2.7

I would like to define a function in Python, say N(d), recursively; with the following property: It sums the products a*b*N(a)N(b), for a and b integers greater than or equal to 0, and a + b = d, d is the variable. thanks.

**Added**

N(1)=N(2)=1

Comment: Okay.  I would like you to define it too!  We're on the same page :)

Comment: @PeterVaro I don't know how to define functions recursively in python and I'm also having problems with the summation, I don't know the code for the summation over two indexes.

Comment: I believe all recursive conditions should include a base condition and  I dont see one here

Comment: @Jr. I'm sure you know how to define a non-recursive function, right? So you should write some code, and share that with us, okay?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I build a recursive function in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479343/how-can-i-build-a-recursive-function-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With memoization comes great performance in recursion.

```
def N(d, memoize = dict()):
    if d == 1 or d == 2: return 1
    if d in memoize: return memoize[d]
    result = 0
    for i in xrange(1, d):
        result += (d - i) * (i) * N(d - i) * N(i)
    memoize[d] = result
    return result

print N(1000)
```

or, in a more concise way,

```
def N(d, memo={1:1, 2:1}):
    # http://oeis.org/A112915
    if d not in memo:
        memo[d] = sum(i * (d - i) * N(i) * N(d - i) for i in range(1, d))
    return memo[d]
```

Comment: I'd say this is _only_ possible with memoization.

Comment: @thg435 You are right. I ran the accepted solution for 1000 an hour back and it hasnt returned yet. :(

Comment: @thefourtheye: given that it gonna make roughly `195862343626786168428215594037354720883766227074392321135543758255826458866178503635670861311201194365023670769907049237918659938088980579535606329667844988744832625955306785759705892478365161670280059276679795265352436713425643620453565358970975803628223137500071162134155119169931688269254128630357946106789669416856086265219024651601168577321267615419985027793981221062495757027954891372595398605645786729791062435387274491014871947962543086223794720908470089299096719291852` recursive calls, you'll have to wait a bit ;)

Comment: @thg435 How did you get N(1000)? i'm getting "maximum recursion depth exceeded", what does it mean? PS: The script works fine up to 900

Answer (score 1):

```
def N(d):
    if d == 1:
        return 1
    if d == 2:
        return 1
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1,d):
        tmp1 = N(i)
        tmp2 = N(d-i)
        sum += i*(d-i)*tmp1*tmp2
    return sum

print N(5)
```

Comment: @Jr.Please check my memoized version also.