# Recursivity in Python returns none, an other way to do it

Tags: python, recursion, return-type

I am starting python and I have a little problem with the return in python.
So, the final value of Lc, my result list is correct in my recursive function cpRec, but
when it returns it, I get None in the function cp2. I can use a global value for Lc, and the problem is solved, but it's ugly... So is there an other way to do it ?

```
def cpRec(L, Lc, chiffre,cpt):
  if len(L) == 0:
    Lc += [cpt]
    #print Lc <- if I print here, the result is good.
    return Lc
  else:
    first = L.pop(0)
    if first == chiffre:
        cpRec(L, Lc, chiffre, cpt+ 1)
    else:
        Lc += [cpt]
        cpRec(L, Lc, first, 1)

def cp2(L):
  Lc =[L[0]]
  return cpRec(L,Lc, L[0], 0)

print(cp2([0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1])) #<- print None instead of Lc
```

Using the global like this is working but it's ugly:

```
def cpRec(L,chiffre,cpt):
  global Lc
  if len(L) == 0:
    Lc += [cpt]
  else:
    first = L.pop(0)
    if first == chiffre:
        cpRec(L, chiffre, cpt+ 1)
    else:
        Lc += [cpt]
        cpRec(L,first, 1)

def cp2(L):
  global Lc
  Lc =[L[0]]
  cpRec(L, L[0], 0)
  return Lc

print(cp2([0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1]))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I build a recursive function in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479343/how-can-i-build-a-recursive-function-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place a `return` before your recursive calls to `cpRec`.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding 'return' statement to those two recursive `cpRec` calls:

```
def cpRec(L, Lc, chiffre,cpt):
  if len(L) == 0:
    Lc += [cpt]
    #print Lc <- if I print here, the result is good.
    return Lc
  else:
    first = L.pop(0)
    if first == chiffre:
        return cpRec(L, Lc, chiffre, cpt+ 1)
    else:
        Lc += [cpt]
        return cpRec(L, Lc, first, 1)
```