# Tkinter unintentional recursion with menu bar command...cause?

Tags: python, recursion, tkinter

I'm trying to make a Python GUI using `tkinter`, and I need a menu item that opens another copy of the main window.  I tried to do the following code, and when I ran the program, it froze for a bit, then opened a large number of windows.  The last error message printed is below.

I have two questions.

1. How can I accomplish the task of making the "New" button open a new window and instance of the `TheThing` class? (In IDLE, `File > New File` has the behavior I'm seeking.)
2. Why is this error happening?

   ```
   RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
   ```

My code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class TheThing:
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.option_add('*tearOff', False)

        menubar = tk.Menu(root)
        root.config(menu = menubar)

        file = tk.Menu(menubar)
        menubar.add_cascade(menu = file, label = "File")
        file.add_command(label = 'New', command = doathing())

def doathing():
    thing1 = tk.Tk()
    thing2 = TheThing(thing1)

def main():
    win = tk.Tk()
    do = TheThing(win)
    win.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Places I've already looked for answers:

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039485/tkinter-runtimeerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded) seemed like it was having a very similar problem.  I may be able to study that and find a solution, but I still won't understand the problem.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955575/maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-while-calling-a-python-object) was about recursion, python, and tkinter, but seemed to be about more the `after` thing.

Comment: `command = doathing()` is executing the callback right away (and in the callback creates a new window, in an endless recursion) and binds its result to the `command` parameter. remove the `()`. Also, what's that supposed to do anyway?

Comment: That fixed it.  I removed the `()`, and it seemingly works as intended.  It's supposed to open a new window, exactly like the old window.  The Python IDLE text editor has this behavior, under `File > New File`.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
    file.add_command(label = 'New', command = doathing())
```

Here, you *execute* the `doathing` callback and then try to bind its result (which is `None`) to the command. In this specific case, this also leads to an infinite recursion, as the callback will create a new instance of the frame, which will again execute the callback, which will create another frame, and so on. Instead of calling the function, you have to bind the function *itself* to the command.

```
    file.add_command(label = 'New', command = doathing)  # no ()
```

In case you need to pass parameters to that function (not the case here) you can use a `lambda`:

```
    file.add_command(label = 'New', command = lambda: doathing(params))
```

---

Also, instead of creating another `Tk` instance you should probably just create a [`Toplevel`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) instance in the callback, i.e.

```
def doathing():
    thing1 = tk.Toplevel()
    thing2 = TheThing(thing1)
```

Comment: Thank you.  Your answer was extremely helpful.  Not only did you answer the question I'd asked, but you answered a lot about some questions I was wondering as I was reading your answer.