# How can I apply a function to itself?

Tags: python

Suppose I have function, `f`, which takes in some variable and returns a variable of the same type.  For simplicity, let's say

```
def f(x):
    return x/2+1
```

I'm interested in applying `f` to itself over and over.  Something like `f(f(f(...(f(x))...)))`.

I could do this like

```
s = f(x)
for i in range(100):
    s = f(s)
```

But I was wondering if there was a simpler, less verbose way to doing the same thing.  I wan't to avoid `for` loops (just as a challenge to myself).  Is there maybe some way of using `map` or a similar function to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there maybe some way of using `map` or a similar function to accomplish this?

Not `map`, but `reduce`. I wouldn't use it for this, but you could call `reduce` on an *n*-item sequence to cause `f` to be called *n* times. For example:

```
>>> def f(x):
...   return x+1
... 
>>> reduce(lambda n,_: f(n), range(100), 42)
142
```

Explanation:

- `n` is assigned each successive return value of `f`.
- `_` is the list of numbers from `range(100)`. These numbers are all ignored. All that matters is how many there are.
- `42` is the starting value.

`100` nested calls to `f(f(f...(f(42))...))` results in `142`.

Answer (score 5):

In Python, a for loop is the most ergonomic and readable way to do this. So I would consider this mostly an exercise — these are more natural to use in functional languages.

[`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) collapses a list of values to a single value by repeatedly calling a function of two arguments. Here's factorial:

```
>>> import functools, operator
>>> operator.mul(2,3)
6
>>> functools.reduce(operator.mul, range(1, 10), 1)
362880
```

We can abuse this to use a list of values for its length only and ignore the actual contents.

```
>>> def f(x):
...   return x/2+1
... 
>>> functools.reduce(lambda x, y: f(x), range(10), 1)
1.9990234375
```

Or we can string together *n* copies of the (unary) function in a list and collapse them by applying each one to the accumulated value.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> functools.reduce(lambda x, g: g(x), itertools.repeat(f, 10), 1)
1.9990234375
```

Answer (score 2):

While it is not clear from your example if you are trying to calculate a final numerical result or accumulate a list of values, you can use a very simple recursive approach with a lambda function:

Single value:

```
f = lambda x, c = 1:x if c == 100 else f(x/2 + 1, c+1)
>>f(200)
2
```

List of values:

```
f = lambda x, c = 1:x if c == 100 else f(x+[x[-1]/2+1], c+1)
>>f([200])
[200, 101, 51, 26, 14, 8, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

The construct would be recursion. But recursion requires that your call stack ends at some point. Such a case could work with an algorithm such as:

```
if(x == 0):
    return 1
# this will make sure it ends at the preceding line in the next call
return f(x - 1)
```

This is typically the approach used to compute results such as the factorial.

To use an example, adding a requirement (that you only compute if x < 2, just as an example):

```
def f(x):
  if(x < 2):
    return 1
  return f(x/2+1)
```

The key is that there be a point at which the call stack starts returning (to avoid an overflow)

Answer (score 0):

You could add the function itself in the return line of the definition. An example would be the top answer here [How can I build a recursive function in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479343/how-can-i-build-a-recursive-function-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You could factor out recursion:

```
from functools import partial
recurse = partial(lambda g,f,x,n: g(g,f,x,n), # capture g
                  lambda g,f,x,n: n and g(g, f, f(x), n-1) or x)
```

If you're into something better than a one-liner, recursion can be abolished:

```
import itertools
def recurse(f, x, n):
  for _ in itertools.repeat(None, n):
    x = f(x)
  return x
```

Then:

```
>>> f = lambda x: x/2+1
>>> recurse(f, 42, 5)
7.0
>>> f(f(f(42)))
7.0
```

Answer (score -1):

What I think you're asking about is concept called Recursion. You could use something like a lambda function but recursive calls in a for loop aren't inherently bad. I'd go read more about recursive functions in general and then look for python implementations specifically.

Comment: No, for loops are not bad, but I want to avoid them as a challenge.  Recursion is a good all, I had forgotten about that.